# Maximum likelihood estimator for binomial model

Tags: maximum-likelihood, binomial-distribution

The main problem I'm having is that I'm getting $\hat{p}=\frac{\bar{x}}{n}$, not $\frac{x}{n}$.

For some reason, many of the derivations of the MLE for the binomial leave out the product and summation signs. When I do it without the product and summation signs, I get $\frac{x}{n}$, but leaving them in I get the following:

$$L=\prod_{i=1}^{n}{n \choose x_i}p^{x_i}(1-p)^{n-k_i}$$
$$\ell=\sum_{i=1}^{n}ln{n \choose x_i}+ln(p)\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i  +ln(1-p)\sum_{i=1}^{n}(n-x_i)$$

$$\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial p}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i}{p}-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(n-x_i)}{1-p}$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i-\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_ip=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(n-x_i)p$$

$$p=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(n-x_i)+\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i}$$

$$p=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x}{n\cdot n}$$

$$p=\frac{\bar{x}}{n}$$

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing multiple binomial experiments with a single binomial experiment. Imagine you flip a coin 10 times and want to estimate the probability of Heads. If you observe 3 Heads, you predict $\hat{p} = \frac{3}{10}$. This is a sum of **bernoullis**, i.e. a single binomial experiment.

You're describing a sum of **binomials**, which corresponds to e.g. repeating your 10 flip experiment 5 times and observing:

$$X_1 = 3H$$
$$X_2 = 4H$$
$$X_3 = 2H$$
$$X_4 = 3H$$
$$X_5 = 4H$$

But if you think about it, doing 5 separate experiments in which you flip the coin 10 times is the same as doing a single experiment where you flip the coin 50 times. In this "condensed" experiment, we would estimate:

$$\hat{p} = \frac{16}{50} = \frac{\frac{16}{5}}{10} = \frac{\bar{x}}{n}$$

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if I may be a bit pedantic: you don't calculate the MLE "for the Binomial" because we usually don't estimate distributions, but rather *parameters* of distributions. In your case you wish to estimate the "p parameter" of the Binomial, i.e. the probability of "success" in the underlying Bernoulli trials.

The estimate $\hat{p} = \frac{\bar{x}}{n}$ seems correct to me, because the MLE of the population mean $\mu$ is the sample mean $\bar{x}$, and the population mean of the Binomial is $\mu = n p$ where $n$ is the number of Bernoulli trials what I assume to be known in this case.